# Can a bin bag supply enough air to escape?

Tags: science-based, oxygen

A reasonably healthy adult human is trapped in a burning building.

The corridor to the outside is not on fire yet but is filled with smoke (and they can't just crawl under it).

Since their eyes are useless in the passageway anyway they find a bin bag, inflate it as much as they can and then put it over their head. Sealing it around their neck as best they can they open the door and walk down the passageway trailing one hand against a wall to keep their bearings.

1. Does this work? Can they survive for a while this way?
2. How long can they survive for? How long can the corridor be and they still have a chance to escape?

Comment: Hoping this is just a dialect thing, but: What's a "bin bag?"

Comment: How big are your bags? In US, standard household garbage bag is 13 gallons (49 liters).

Comment: Though the idea of someone running around a burning building with a bag over their head is fantastic, what's stopping them from carrying the sealed air bag in their hands and bringing it to their mouth whenever they need to take a breath?

Comment: They [have these](https://www.honeywellsafety.com/Products/Respiratory_Protection/EEBD_(Emergency_Escape_Breathing_Devices).aspx?site=/uk) in the Navy! They are for evacuating a space when you see smoke. If there is already a fire they will melt on to your face...so take it off if you see a fire.

Comment: Maybe your survivors should not pull the bags over their heads, but rather put them to their mouths?

Comment: @Alexander That does have several advantages - particularly if you have some old swimming goggles or something you can put on to protect your eyes at the same time. It's probably easier to make a decent seal that way too.

Comment: This questions is currently being VTC'd on as being off-topic, and I kind of agree as I do not see any worldbuilding aspect to it and it is "merely" a fact-checking question. Not quite sure what the current site-stance on fact-checking for authors is, but I see little connection to worldbuilding here.

Answer (score 8):

Every breath exchange about 2 liters of air. A 50 liters bag would suffice for at most 25 breaths, which, assuming two breaths per minute (deep breaths with some apnea to save air), should be enough for about 12 minutes. Assuming that the subject can control his breathing under stress and knows where to go, it might work.

However, there are several reasons why this sounds like a bad idea:

- Not looking where you are going: yes, there is smoke, but still your eyes can tell you if you are stepping on a burning beam, a collapsed wall or stairs.
- Using only your hands to get track of where you are: when firemen do it, they are trained to use the back of their hands, to avoid that touching a live electric wire gets them electrocuted. Average Joe probably ignores it.
- Using only your hands to get track of where you are: what if you touch a hot wall?
- Bin bag is plastic: if it hits hot air or flames, it will melt or catch fire. Molten plastic on your face is not fun at all! And a full bin bag would increase the guy's height.

Comment: Lots of great YouTube videos showing just how ferociously hot smoke can be.

Comment: This says 0.5 liter per normal breath: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_volume. But deeper breaths can take several times more. So 10-15 is probably right. A better Q is if shallow breaths are better than deep ones. Oh yeah, and the bag better be transparent so your protagonist can see.

Comment: It's worth noting that humans are more than capable of rebreathing the air that they've already breathed - we don't use up all the oxygen in a breath in our lungs.  It's the concentration of CO2 that becomes problematic.

Comment: @jdunlop, yes, and that will stay in the bin bag, too

Comment: Two breaths a minute sounds awfully low.  In a meditation class, one of the goals was getting down to four per minute.  I can do that sitting down calmly, but I'd be taking more breaths running through a hazardous area.

Comment: Physically active person will use more than a tidal volume (though not 2 liters, unless activity is vigorous), and will breathe more frequently than 2 breaths per minute.

Comment: "Oxygen will flow to the mask, even if the bag does not inflate."  The bag is actually there for people who are breathing faster than they should.  It lets them re-breathe the oxygenated air several times before letting it out into the airline cabin.  Some of the issues with number of breaths here may be resolved by looking at mass of O2 used and CO2 produced.  I can write an answer to that end, if desired.

Answer (score 5):

The primary issue isn't the size of the bag or the ability to move without seeing, but rather the heat inside the corridor.

Fire is very hot, and the air inside a fire is full of aerosolized particles from burning materials which are also transferring a lot of the heat energy. Going from memory, the air at the top of a burning room can be up to 700 degrees F, more than enough to melt the plastic bag or cause it to burst into flames (hardly what you want over your head).

[image]

*Image of a "rollover" fire, from the Kansas Fire and Rescue Institute*

Even putting it over your head and lying down at ground level isn't likely to work, the bag only has a limited amount of air and oxygen inside, so after a short while (varies depending on the size of the bag and your rate of breathing), the bag will be filled with your CO2 and you will suffocate.

Most fire safety warnings tell you to avoid smoke filled corridors, and retreat back into your room, sealing the bottom of the door with a wet towel or similar object to prevent smoke from entering your room. Going to a window may work, assuming smoke or flame isn't rising along that side of the building, and if the side is clear, you will have a supply of fresh air and a possible avenue of escape or rescue (depending on the size of the building and capabilities of the fire department). As an aside, the image of rooms filled with flames is an artifact of Hollywood (flames provide light and high contrast for the viewer to see the action). Reality is a dark, smoke filled space.

[image]

*More like this*

So short answer is **NO**. Do *NOT* move into a smoke filled corridor or room to avoid asphyxiation from the smoke and lung damage from the superheated air, and retreat into a safe area clear fo smoke and with potential access to the outside and safety.

Comment: The question specifies that "corridor to the outside is not on fire yet". Though I agree the moving through the smoke-filled building with a bag on your head may not be the best idea.

Comment: I think this basic fire-safety and movie-puncturing answer has great value. Even if the corridor is "not on fire yet," this answer shows that the trapped person *cannot accurately determine that fact*, and may indeed blunder into any of several nasty and unnecessary forms of death.

Comment: While I agree your advice is in most cases correct - it doesn't really answer the question. The question was actually originally inspired by the Grenfell tower situation where people were trapped in rooms, the stairs to the outside were filled with smoke, and containment had failed. Staying put was a death sentence but the central stairwell was so full of smoke that it couldn't be used to escape.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a rather long time, but the time depends on a whole host of factors.

Others have pointed out that CO2 is a limiting factor, but it turns out not to be the case.  If the CO2 gets above 10kPA blood gas pressure, [hypercapnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercapnia) sets in.

> In severe hypercapnia (generally PaCO2 greater than 10 kPa or 75 mmHg), symptomatology progresses to disorientation, panic, hyperventilation, convulsions, unconsciousness, and eventually death.

Just to set some numbers, in normal atmospheres, O2 is 21kPa.  Anything below 16kPa is [considered fatal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure).  CO2 is basically nonexistent (0.04kPa).  For the most part, the body breathes out 1L CO2 for every 1L of O2 it consumes (it's actually more complicated, but that's a decent first order approximation).  This means that if O2 falls from 21kPa to 16kPa, CO2 will rise to 5pKa, which is below the fatal range for CO2.  That's not to say you'll be comfortable.  But you're in a fire, with a bag over your head.  Comfort went out the window a long time ago (say... window... that's a good idea!)

So now we know that we can consume an amount of O2 associated with 5kPa.  We'd like to convert that to something more helpful, and it turns out that for the next part, converting that into liters of pure O2 is useful.  Because we're doing all of this at standard atmospheric pressure, our total air pressure is 101kPa.  That means for every 20L of air we have in our bag, we have 1L that we can consume before we reach fatally low levels of O2.

The final number we need is VO2max.  VO2max is a measure of how much oxygen we can consume in a maximum intensity setting.  This is an estimated number.  It's unsafe to run your heart this hard. But guess what: the building is on fire!  VO2max it is!

[VO2max for a healthy untrained adult male](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_max) is on the order of $35–40 \frac{mL}{kg\cdot min}$.  This means that, every minute, the male consumes 35-40mL of O2 per kilogram of body mass.  If we pick the 40 number, that means total oxygen intake is $.04Mt$ liters where $M$ is their mass and $t$ is time in minutex.  Since we have $0.05V$ liters of O2 available (where V is the volume of the bag in liters), the total survival time is
$$0.05V = 0.04Mt$$
$$t = \frac{1.25V}{M}$$

For an average male, $M=70$ (kg).  For a "standard household garbage bag," $V=49$ (L).  Plug these together and you get $t=0.875min$, or roughly 50 seconds.

That's not very long.  Now there are some mitigating factors.  You might not actually operate at VO2 max in this panicked state.  That would increase your longevity.  Women also have a lower VO2max.  Also, you have a full bloodstream full of oxygen, which will help.  You may also be able to function for a while at lower levels of O2 concentration.  The human body can do some amazing things when it has to.

Between all of these fuzzy factors, I'd say you have anywhere from 1 minute to 5 minutes.  The bag itself buys you a little.  But the big thing is not breathing in smoke.  Breathing smoke will take you out far faster.

Comment: Fire on not, "maximum intensity setting" requires maximum physical activity. If people are nervous, but not running, they may be hyperventilating, but please note that their oxygen consumption will not be anywhere near VO2max - they will just be breathing more oxygen back into the bag.

Comment: @Alexander Very true.  On the other hand, if they're running around panicked (which they probably are, with a plastic bag over their head in the fire), they may get to a reasonable fraction.  It certainly shows that there's a rather large uncertainty factor in the process.